# C API and lua types

Tags: c, lua

If you check some `lua` [docs](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.html), you can see:

> There are eight basic types in Lua: nil, boolean, number, string,
>   userdata, function, thread, and table.

What purpose then do the C API functions, such as `lua_pushunsigned()` and `lua_pushinteger()` serve, since a `lua` number type is usually defined as some floating point type (e.g. `double`)? Why not just `lua_pushnumber()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation for [lua_pushinteger](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lapi.c.html#lua_pushinteger) and [lua_pushnumber](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lapi.c.html#lua_pushnumber) are identical except for a check for signalling NaN values in pushnumber. The integer passed to pushinteger is cast to a `lua_Number` (which is a [`double` by default](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lua.h.html#lua_Number)) before pushing it to the Lua stack.

The main advantage of the additional abstraction here is that the exact implementation of the type conversion is handled by Lua and not by the user. For example, you will notice that the casting done for [pushunsigned](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lapi.c.html#lua_pushunsigned) is a little more complex than expected for performance reasons. However, if you prefer to do the casting yourself (and you know the types of `lua_Number` and `lua_Integer` beforehand) there is no harm in just calling pushnumber everywhere.

Note that the upcoming Lua 5.3 is planned to [introduce an integer number type](http://www.lua.org/work/doc/#changes) to the language, so the difference between the API functions is probably going to become more relevant there. However, it is still too early to predict the final impact of this change on the API.